# Null input buffer in orbeon

Tags: orbeon

On selecting radio button in orbeon xml, we are getting Null Input buffer exception in error dialog box. This issue is coming in IE 8 browser & above, its working fine in IE 6.
We have searched, we have got below link, which is showing this issue is still open:

http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=312234&group_id=168&atid=350207

Could anyone let us know whether this issue is still open in latest orbeon 3.9?

We have tried to give some workaround but still we are facing issue. Below is the analysis:

Scenario: Add/Delete radio button inside repeat is throwing the below error. 
Work around :On Tomcat local, we have set the property "encrypt-item-values" to false( this will not encrypt the option values) and the issue is resolved, but the option is not getting selected and data is not getting saved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are pointing to only arrises if you have your own JavaScript code that sets the value of a radio button, not if you click on the page to select a value, which seems to be what you are doing.

We, at Orbeon, are not aware of any issue like the one you describe with the latest code. I would encourage you to:

1. Try your case with a PE or CE nightly build, which you can get form the [download page](http://www.orbeon.com/forms/download).
2. If you can reproduce this with the PE or CE nightly build, try to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, paste it as a [Gist](http://gist.github.com/), and post a comment below so we can look into it.

Comment: Thanks. We will take latest build and will try to reproduce and We will get back to you.